# How to repeate NSTimer every day at particular time in iOS app

Tags: ios, nstimer, uilocalnotification, badge

I have method which call the sqlite method to get data and then display count to application badge number in ip. I want that the method should be called every day at 12.5 am so that it has new count for the day. I am doing in following way:

```
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:300 target:self selector:@selector(makeNotificationRequest:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I am calling this `NSTimer` in when application goes in background state.

```
-(void)makeNotificationRequest:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self repeatedMethod];
}

- (void)repeatedMethod {
    SOWObject *object =[[SOWObject alloc]init];
    [object getBadgeNumber:[self getDBPath]];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber=badgeArray.count;
}
```

Comment: You can schedule silent local notifications for this may be?

Comment: Can you please advise some process for this

Comment: i guess you are lookin for background sync what we call pooling

Comment: Does it matter what timezone and if the user changes timezones? And if your app isn't running, do you perform once on startup or do you need to perform for each missed event?